# Dimensionality for stacked LSTM network in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In reviewing the numerous similar questions concerning multidimensional inputs and a stacked LSTM RNN I have not found an example which lays out the dimensionality for the `initial_state` placeholder and following `rnn_tuple_state` below.  The attempted `[lstm_num_layers, 2, None, lstm_num_cells, 2]` is an extension of the code from these examples (http://monik.in/a-noobs-guide-to-implementing-rnn-lstm-using-tensorflow/, https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/using-the-tensorflow-multilayered-lstm-api-f6e7da7bbe40) with an extra dimension of `feature_dim` added at the end for the multiple values at each time step of the features (this doesn't work but instead produces a `ValueError` due to mismatched dimensions in the `tensorflow.nn.dynamic_rnn` call).

```
time_steps = 10
feature_dim = 2
label_dim = 4
lstm_num_layers = 3
lstm_num_cells = 100
dropout_rate = 0.8

# None is to allow for variable size batches
features = tensorflow.placeholder(tensorflow.float32,
                                  [None, time_steps, feature_dim])
labels = tensorflow.placeholder(tensorflow.float32, [None, label_dim])

cell = tensorflow.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    [tensorflow.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(
        lstm_num_cells,
        dropout_keep_prob = dropout_rate)] * lstm_num_layers,
    state_is_tuple = True)

# not sure of the dimensionality for the initial state
initial_state = tensorflow.placeholder(
    tensorflow.float32,
    [lstm_num_layers, 2, None, lstm_num_cells, feature_dim])
# which impacts these two lines as well
state_per_layer_list = tensorflow.unstack(initial_state, axis = 0)
rnn_tuple_state = tuple(
    [tensorflow.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(
        state_per_layer_list[i][0],
        state_per_layer_list[i][1]) for i in range(lstm_num_layers)])

# also not sure if expanding the feature dimensions is correct here
outputs, state = tensorflow.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell, tensorflow.expand_dims(features, -1),
    initial_state = rnn_tuple_state)
```

What would be most helpful is an explanation of the generic situation where:

- each time step has *N* values
- each time sequence has *S* steps
- each batch has *B* sequences
- each output has *R* values
- there are *L* hidden LSTM layers in the network
- each layer has *M* number of nodes

so the pseudocode version of this would be:

```
# B, S, N, and R are undefined values for the purpose of this question
features = tensorflow.placeholder(tensorflow.float32, [B, S, N])
labels = tensorflow.placeholder(tensorflow.float32, [B, R])
...
```

which if I could finish I wouldn't be asking here in the first place.  Thanks in advance.  Any comments on relevant best practices welcome.

Comment: Can you give us the full error traceback?

Comment: @Engineero The full traceback is too long but the complete error is `ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 2. Shapes are [1] and [2]. for 'rnn/while/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell_0/layer_norm_basic_lstm_cell/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [?,2,1], [?,100,2], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <1>.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error the following produces a stacked LSTM `dynamic_rnn` regardless of the dimensionality of the features:

```
time_steps = 10
feature_dim = 2
label_dim = 4
lstm_num_layers = 3
lstm_num_cells = 100
dropout_rate = 0.8
learning_rate = 0.001

features = tensorflow.placeholder(
    tensorflow.float32, [None, time_steps, feature_dim])
labels = tensorflow.placeholder(
    tensorflow.float32, [None, label_dim])

cell_list = []
for _ in range(lstm_num_layers):
    cell_list.append(
        tensorflow.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(lstm_num_cells,
                                                      dropout_keep_prob=dropout_rate))
cell = tensorflow.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cell_list, state_is_tuple=True)
initial_state = tensorflow.placeholder(
    tensorflow.float32, [lstm_num_layers, 2, None, lstm_num_cells])
state_per_layer_list = tensorflow.unstack(initial_state, axis=0)
rnn_tuple_state = tuple(
    [tensorflow.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(
        state_per_layer_list[i][0],
        state_per_layer_list[i][1]) for i in range(lstm_num_layers)])
state_series, last_state = tensorflow.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=cell, inputs=features, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)

hidden_layer_output = tensorflow.transpose(state_series, [1, 0, 2])
last_output = tensorflow.gather(hidden_layer_output, int(
    hidden_layer_output.get_shape()[0]) - 1)

weights = tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.random_normal(
    [lstm_num_cells, int(labels.get_shape()[1])]))
biases = tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.constant(
    0.0, shape=[labels.get_shape()[1]]))
predictions = tensorflow.matmul(last_output, weights) + biases
mean_squared_error = tensorflow.reduce_mean(
    tensorflow.square(predictions - labels))
minimize_error = tensorflow.train.RMSPropOptimizer(
    learning_rate).minimize(mean_squared_error)
```

Part of what started this journey down one of many proverbial rabbit holes was the previously referenced examples reshaped the output to accommodate a classifier instead of a regressor (which is what I was attempting to build).  Since this is independent of the feature dimensionality it serves as a generic template for this use case.